# specifying default format in routing spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following rspec routing spec but I need to specify `:defaults => { :format => 'json' }` in the post; how would I do this?

spec:

```
it "should route to all-locations-nav" do
  {:post => locations_nav_path }.should route_to(:controller => "api", :action => "locations_nav")
end
```

**edit #1**
so playing around, it looks like this fixes it:

```
it "should route to all-locations-nav" do
  {:post => locations_nav_path }.should route_to(:controller => "api", :action => "locations_nav", :format => "json")
end
```

but was curious if this is documented anywhere?

Answer (score 6):

Just set the format in the spec like this ...

```
it "routes to #create" do
  expect(:post => "/post").to route_to("posts#create", :format => :json)
end
```

**Long explanation ...**

The behavior you're seeing is not specific to `:format`, but is rather a relationship between the symbols you see in `rake routes` and the symbols that you pass to `route_to`.

For instance, given your example above, I'd expect something like the following when you run `rake routes`:

`locations_nav   POST   /api/locations_nav(.:format)    api#locations_nav`

The `:controller` and `:action` aren't explicitly flagged in the `rake routes` response, as those are built into Rails' MVC structure, but the `:format` is shown explicitly, and passing the `:format` to `route_to` taps into this. For example ...

Similarly, you'll probably see a few `:id` references in your `rake routes` output, which would be leveraged by passing an `:id` parameter to `route_to`.

Some additional examples around routing in RSpec can be seen in the ["rspec-rails" documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/2.14.0/#route_to).

Internally, RSpec's `route_to` delegates to Rails' `assert_recognizes`, which you can see documented in the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_recognizes).